# Ubuntu class string has no member remove

Tags: arduino-ide, library, string, compilation-errors

I am running some code that works fine on my windows system using the .remove method.  On Ubuntu 16.04 I get the following errror:

```
error: ‘class String’ has no member named ‘remove’
```

To see if it was installation, I uninstalled arduino with

```
sudo apt-get purge arduino arduino-core
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install arduino arduino-core
```

and the issue remains.  I have seen some people say opening arduino through the terminal ([from this](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2512)), although that does not fix it.

Arduino version 
2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you running 1.0.5?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I didn't realize that, for some reason I thought it was 2.  Ubuntu is installing 1.0.5 even after the updated package list, is arduino not maintained on the repo? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You'll probably have to download the tarball from the Arduino site, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `remove` method was added to the `String` class in 1.0.6.

Installing Arduino IDE from the Ubuntu repository gets you a really old package (1.0.5).

You should [download](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) and install the newest version from the official Arduino page.

Comment: Yep, that's what I always do. Download the newest version and bang it into some place like your home directory.